# While loop not working properly in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

So I am trying to find 6th prime number, and the while loop in getPrime is not working properly. It is supposed to end when count is bigger than num, but it doesn't.
It'd be great if you could help me find out why.

```
import math

def isPrime(num):
    if num == 1:
        return False
    if num % 2 == 0 and num > 2:
        return False
    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(num))+1, 2):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def getPrime(num):
    count = 1
    while count < num:
        for i in range(1, 20):
            #print "check"
            if isPrime(i):
                print "prime", i
                count += 1
                print "count", count
            else:
                continue
    print i
    return i

getPrime(6)
```

Comment: So in short you want to know how many prime numbers are between 0 and num or get the highest prime number in some range? Why you are looking for prime numbers only in array [1, 20]?

Comment: Why are you using range(1, 20) exactly?

Comment: Also, `i` may not have been defined/initialized at all when you get to the end of the function.

Comment: What is problem statement?? `getPrime(6)` ?? want first 6 prime numbers or prime numbers from the first 6 numbers??

Comment: He wants the 6th prime number starting at 1. So that is: 1, 3, 5, 7, 11, **13**.

Comment: your code actually doesn't loop forever AFAICT, did you try with another range when it got stuck?

Comment: People discuss about that for a long time now, no need to do that here... Anyway, I've put it there, because the `isPrime` function will return `True` when given 1 as the argument.

Comment: @1Darco1 No it won't `if num == 1: return False`. I deleted my last comment as 13 is the 6th prime. You missed 2 from your list and I didn't check.

Comment: You're right. Oh well, I am really stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only checking the value of count at the end of the for loop so you will always end up with the full range of 1-20 being tested. Why is the range limited to 20?

You don't need a for loop at all. Use the while loop to keep finding primes until you have `num` of them.

Try something like:

```
def getPrime(num):
    count = 0 
    i = 1 
    highPrime = None 
    while count < num:
        if isPrime(i):
            count += 1
            highPrime = i 
        i += 1
    return highPrime
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `getPrime()` function, when `isPrime(i)` returns `False`, you are not incrementing the `count` variable. So the `while count < num` loop gets stuck at that point.

Update: Well, that was my first impression from looking at the code. But then I noticed the nested loop. So I could have misread what was going on.

What I recommend at this point is stepping through the code in a debugger so you can see for yourself what is happening. Do you have a Python debugger available?

You can answer almost any question like this yourself if you have a good debugger and know how to use it. Then you won't have to wait for your friends on Stack Overflow to take guesses about what's going wrong! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because your range statement is within the body of the while statement.  In another language you might use a do... until statement, but in Python the way to do it is just to add a conditional break statement, e.g. I have corrected your code to:

```
def getPrime(num):
    count = 1
    for i in range(1, 20):
        if count > num: break
        if isPrime(i):
            highestPrime = i
            count += 1
    return highestPrime
```

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, but it is still not correct completely. Add a `highestPrime` variable before the loop and assign the current value of i to it whenever i is a prime number. Then you can return `highestPrime` instead of i which may have no value.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify getPrime, there is no need for a while loop:

```
def getPrime(num, r):
    gen = (i for i in r if isPrime(i))
    primes = zip(*zip(range(num), gen))[1]
    return primes[num-1] if len(primes) >= num else None

>>> print getPrime(6, xrange(1, 20))
13
>>> print getPrime(6, xrange(100, 500))
127
```