# How to find first n number of prime numbers in python?unable to follow the scope of a variable?

Tags: python

```
f=0
c=1
n=raw_input("Enter the value of n")
while c<n:
    for i in range(2,100):
        for j in range(1,i):
            if i%j == 0:
                f =f+1
        if f == 1:
            print i
            c = c+1
        f = 0
```

If `n` is `5` then the output should print the first 5 prime numbers.

```
2,3,5,7,11
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Right off the bat, `raw_input` returns a string, so you probably want to convert it into an integer by doing `n=int(raw_input(...))`.

Comment: if i assign 5 to n(without getting the input) it prints prime number from 1 to 100 .[.2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 ]

Comment: [Do you know this person?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426834/while-loop-not-working-properly-in-python/28428975) You are doing almost exactly the same thing wrong. See my answer for that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few mistakes. You do not parse `n` as integer, you have an unnecessary loop, you inistailise `c` with a wrong value.

Here is a corrected version

```
c = 0
n=int(raw_input("Enter the value of n"))
i = 2
while True:
    for j in range(2,i):
        if i % j == 0:
            break
    else:
        print i
        c = c + 1
    if c == n:
        break
    i += 1
```

Comment: I'd say it was the for loop that was unnecessary. What happens if I type 26 in as n?

Comment: Good point (post edited). I somehow assumed form OP that we don't care about primes above 100, but that assumption does not make anything easier.

Comment: @thiruvenkadam can you help me to code using for...else

Comment: What kind of help? Because the above program itself uses `for... else` instead of using a temporary flag to check whether a number is prime or not.

Answer (score 0):

Copy of answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426834/while-loop-not-working-properly-in-python/28428975) question.

You're only checking the value of count at the end of the for loop so you will always end up with the full range of 1-100 being tested. Why is the range limited to 100?

You don't need a for loop at all. Use the while loop to keep finding primes until you have `num` of them.

Try something like:

```
import math
def isPrime(num):#this function courtesy of @JinnyCho
    if num == 1:
        return False
    if num % 2 == 0 and num > 2:
        return False
    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(num))+1, 2):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def getPrimes(num):
    count = 0 
    i = 1 
    highPrime = None 
    while count < num:
        if isPrime(i):
            count += 1
            yield i
        i += 1

n = int(raw_input("Enter the value of n: "))
list(getPrimes(n))
```

Comment: Enter the value of n:  13
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 22, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 16, in getPrimes
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in isPrime
NameError: global name 'math' is not defined

Comment: Sorry. You need import math at the top

Comment: Fixed. Added import and conversion to int.